Indentation problem in the TOC
I am trying to add a preface to a table of contents. I am currently using the following command:
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Preface}

since the entry in question should be displayed as a section rather than a chapter. However, I would like to remove the indentation for only the first line (and keep it for the rest). Is that possible?

Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0ex}{13.5ex}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter*{PREFACE}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Preface}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{TITLE}
\section{Preliminaries}

\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}. Note, that at least the used class and already used packages to modify the ToC would be needed. But IMHO using a not numbered chapter for the preface and then using chapter instead of section would be the better.

Sure. However, chapter entries should not to have numbers. Also, titles are slightly different.

Because your preface is a not numbered chapter, the ToC entry should also be a not numbered chapter. In the frontmatter you need only \chapter{…} to do so:
\documentclass{book}% 10pt is the default of book an therefore not needed.

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0ex}{13.5ex}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{PREFACE}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{TITLE}
\section{Preliminaries}

\end{document}


If you insist on an inconsistent table of contents, this can of course also be cobbled together:
% NOTE: THIS IS ONLY FOR DEMONSTRATION.
%       I DO NOT RECOMMEND TO DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS.
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0ex}{13.5ex}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter*{PREFACE}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\hskip -1.5em Preface}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{TITLE}
\section{Preliminaries}

\end{document}



Well, I'm trying to recreate an existing format. So, no options.
